# Return Promise by Aggregating function calls by synchronous, callback driven using setTimeout, promise based

Tags: javascript, promise

How to pass a callback that waits for the setTimeout to finish and return a promise.

Is there any tweak that can be done here to fix this, when a callback is passed from the function which makes the function to resolve after setTimeout

Or call `getB` before `promise.all()` and keep the result ready etc

```js
function getA() {
  return "A";
}
function getB(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback("B");
  }, 10);
}

function getC() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => "C");
}

function getABC() {
  //need to work here only
  const cb = (val) => val;
  return Promise.all([getA(), getB(cb), getC()]);
}

getABC().then((arr) => console.log(arr));
// expected output [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
```

The expected output is `[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]` but receiving `[ 'A', undefined, 'C' ]`
what changes should I make here?

Comment: Wrap body of getB with a promise

Comment: you're not returning at all from getB, but otherwise just use a Promise based timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71450503/return-promise-by-aggregating-function-calls-by-synchronous-callback-driven-usi/71450565?noredirect=1#comment126290301_71450565):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZzAQ2AYwBZQLxQDwAqAfABQBuyANgK4QBcUBAlDkVGQPZwAmA3ALAAoUJCgBJAHacA1hABOOKCW6IU6DA3hJUmFtjaceAwUIBm1CWmBwOEqAHMIwAIJKWAbyFQocp9Tl2AETOgcYAvkJmFlY2do7AAEJKaFSUAEbIaNKaqjoYHl5QCE4EcAC2EBzUwCQkemyegt7eKZTpmdIkgQmBTMbeYQA0UACMAAx9QhEmguaW1rYOTgDCblCN3r7A-nYACnIcZYgQAHS+CByUZBB1J8AYEBK19VCBy73hkbPRC3FOzglVnV1oU0LYEMAoAB3ZBwYAAMQ4cmWqQyWUUJDgUg4sjkDEkMnkLwkEChUH2h2OJHOl2urCgWMJcmpEAuVwgTEmTR8fgC5IOR2KJ1SJAA2vFnHVhjC4YjkaiOiR4gkmMN4ss6gBdLnTIQSwG3e6PEhgiRs06UDj2LlAA)

```js
function getA () {
  return "A";
}

function getB (callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback("B");
  }, 10);
}

function getC () {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => "C");
}

function getABC () {
  const waitForCallback = (invoker) => new Promise(resolve => invoker(resolve));
  return Promise.all([getA(), waitForCallback(getB), getC()]);
}

getABC().then(console.log);
```

---

Original answer:

Return a promise from `getB`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZzAQ2AYwBZQLxQDwAqAfABQBuyANgK4QBcUBAlDkVGQPZwAmA3ALAAoUJCgBJbhAB2wOKBz5i5KrQbNWjAYKEAzalLSyOUqAHMIwAIJQSLAN5CoUAE4XqzkwCJLnrQF8hXX1DOGMzCwAhGzQqSgAjZDQAawZ4JFRMe0cXNw8oKQgAdygABWcOAFtECBJXBA5KMmhsNgdBJycECwI4CogOamASWw02jo66hqaSGMp4xKSSTwjPJiYtcb8AGigARgAGdey-I8EA7UE9AyMTc2AAYRss9pzgdxMyyuqAOknGms891W-kCl2CN3CVgijxGYygaGMCGA8LiDAk0lk8lwykoLBa7CoG1e71K5SqXW+sRIAG07pZbDs7hEZnEmIyLPdbABdU7nIR06G2b7ADDSGaIhoQb6UDimb5xOBSbjiqT1SgQNZaIA)

```js
function getA () {
  return "A";
}

function getB (callback) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(callback("B"));
    }, 10);
  });
}

function getC () {
  return Promise.resolve("C");
}

function getABC () {
  const cb = (val) => val;
  return Promise.all([getA(), getB(cb), getC()]);
}

getABC().then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: Can we do this? without modifying any functions other than getABC()?

Comment: @FaizHameed Yes, see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for